# Pip not installing Pyserial due to Assertion Error

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the serial output from a device using `Pyserial`. However, the module is not being recognized and `pip install pyserial` keeps giving me an assertion error.

I've tried adding the `pyserial` folder to the path and moving it into the python modules folder.

```
import serial
ImportError: No module named serial

pip install pyserial
AssertionError: c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jdcal-1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO is not a subpath of c:\python27\lib\site-packages\jdcal-1.3-py2.7.egg\
```

I expected it to install but it is giving me this error regarding an unrelated file.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
pip3 install pyserial
```

or

```
sudo easy_install pyserial
```

or as per the docs

```
python -m pip install pyserial
```

https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html#from-pypi

Comment: These are my results:
pip3 install pyserial 
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. 
sudo easy_install pyserial
'sudo' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
python -m pip install pyserial
AssertionError: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jdcal-1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/PKG-INFO is not a subpath of C:\Python27\lib\site-packag
es\jdcal-1.3-py2.7.egg\

Comment: Maybe update your pip python -m pip install --upgrade pip